# Reading from a file and writing to StringIO - Python

Tags: python, string, io

I'm using `Box` Python API to write some tools. Therefore, one of them is to upload a file to `Box`. They use a `StringIO` as the object file.
I need to read a file locally and write its content to the `StringIO` buffer, then pass that to the `Box` API as shown in the code below:

```
def upload_file(self, filename, folder_id='0'):
    assert self.client is not None
    try:
        stream = StringIO.StringIO()
        # replace this line a file read
        stream.write('Box Python SDK Test!')
        stream.seek(0)
        box_file = self.client.folder(folder_id=folder_id).upload_stream(
                                                        stream, filename,
                                                        preflight_check=True)
        return box_file.name
    except BoxAPIException, e:
        self.log.exception(e)
```

Simple enough, how can I read from a local file, and then write to the `StringIO` buffer?

Comment: If you really need a StringIO (likely the file object will do), just do `stream.write(open(filename).read())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to supply an open file instead of as `StringIO` instance. This should do:

```
stream = open('mylocal_file')
```